# When it come to bicycle tyres, what does "cheerful", "sprightlier" mean?

Tags: british-english

The usage of those words can be found in [this review](http://road.cc/content/review/4351-kenda-kwick-roller-700x28c-tyre) of a certain make of bicycle tyres. Unable to understand what the author is trying to say using those adjectives, since they are usually used to describe human personality or mood, but never came across such usage for inanimate objects.

I've to admit that my exposure to Queen's English, is fairly limited, and I was struggling to to use "tyre" instead of "tire".

Comment: There's little need to use *tyre* instead of *tire* for most cases. While the spelling *tyre* is (historically recently) preferred in Britain, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand, people from those countries are aware that the US and Canada use *tire* and would understand your meaning. Unless you've a style-guide to write to that insists on one form or the other, just write clear English in either of them.

Comment: From the title, I thought you meant *cycle* was a verb here, actually, and that you meant “when it **comes** to **recycling** tires”, which is some else altogether. What sort of “cycles” are you talking about? Bicycles?  Motorcycles?  Not enough context here.  Sounds like some sort of regional usage to me.

Comment: @JonHanna I really tire of the debate.  *Tyre* is clearly superior so as to avoid ambiguity with the verb *tire*.

Answer (score 4):

*Cheap and cheerful* is a fairly common collocation used to describe goods of low price, but not bad value for the money: they’re OK, but don’t expect too much. *Sprightly* means that they will give you a lively ride.